# Arduino 433Mhz weather sensor receiver

Tags: temperature-sensor

I want to monitor the temperatur around the house and outside. I want to save the data to mysql and then create some kind of webapplication that displlays the data. It is pretty easy to find temperature sensors that transmitts over 433Mhz, and I have thought about [Telldus tellstick](http://www.telldus.com/products/tellstick) to receive data and store them. This receiver costs about 30 - 40 $ and 10 - 20 $ for each sensor.

But since I just learned that Arduino can be used for everything, I would love to hear more about it.

Can someone please give me an introduction to what I would need to make this solution? The arduino should basicly receive data from 433 Mhz sensors and store it to MySQL.

What woulds be the challanges when doing something like this?

Comment: Where is the MySQL server running? A local computer connected over ... or a remote server, or do you wan't an Arduino capable of running MySQL?

Comment: I have MySql on NAS on my local network, but I also have an windows pc that's always on that can run MySql

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Arduino with an ethernet shield to store the data to a MySQL server on the local network. See this [blog post](http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.dk/2013/04/introducing-mysql-connectorarduino_6.html) for an introduction to a library.

The tellstick is designed to be plugged into a USB host, so it doesn't make much sense in combination with an Arduino. You can get a USB host module but it's an expensive solution and you are using way more hardware than necessary.

Instead you could get 433 MHz receivers dirt cheap on ebay, but I'm afraid they only work on one channel, and there are a bunch of channels in the 433 MHz spectrum. So they might not work with the sensors you are talking about.

Another option would be to use eg. Arduino Pro Mini's in combination with a 433 MHz transmitter, powered by a battery. You could get the temperature reading from the internal sensor, or use an external one. The internal sensor takes quite a bit of calibration work to give a precise reading though.
You can get Pro Mini clones on ebay for a few dollars. You would have to dive into sleep modes and such, if you don't want't the batteries eaten away in a short time. To program it, you'll need an FTDI cable, or another Arduino programmed as an ArduinoISP (In System Programmer).
As an alternative to the Pro Mini board you could use a plain AVR chip, but it will be more work.

Comment: Okey so the best way to make the temperature sensor is to buy a pro mini and add external sensor, battery and 433mhz sender? Can this be made to work with the tellstick receiver? And can I mount any sensor on this pro mini? Like humidity, barometer, light, volume etc?

Comment: The microcontroller on the Pro Mini is the same as on the Uno. You can hook it up to all sorts of sensors. I don't know if it will work with the Tellstick. It might, but you would have to implement a protocol supported by Tellstick yourself. I'm not sure if the cheap 433 MHz modules run on the same frequency (433.92 MHz) as the Tellstick though.